TF-GNN error when training a graph: ValueError: Could not unbatch scalar (rank=0) GraphPiece
I am trying to model an autoencoder of a graph data to best reconstruct the graph but Im facing an issue when trying to do the training.
I created the graph tensor as follows:
edge_sources = train_data['from_encoded'].values
edge_targets = train_data['to_encoded'].values
edge_signs = train_data['sign'].values


node_ids = tf.concat([edge_sources, edge_targets], axis=0)
unique_ids, _ = tf.unique(node_ids)

num_nodes = len(unique_ids)

hidden_state_dim = 64

# Create a GraphTensor from edges and node features
graph = tf_gnn.GraphTensor.from_pieces(
    node_sets={
        "nodes": tf_gnn.NodeSet.from_fields(sizes=[num_nodes], features={'id': unique_ids, 'hidden_state': tf.zeros((num_nodes, hidden_state_dim))})
    },
    edge_sets={
        "edges": tf_gnn.EdgeSet.from_fields(
            sizes=[len(edge_sources)],
            adjacency=tf_gnn.Adjacency.from_indices(
                source=("nodes", edge_sources),
                target=("nodes", edge_targets)
            ),
            features={
                "sign": tf.convert_to_tensor(edge_signs, dtype=tf.float32)
            }
        )
    }
)

Then I created the model this way:
graph_tensor_spec = graph.spec

# Define the GCN model with specified hidden layers
gcn_model = gcn.GCNConv(
        units=64,  # Example hidden layer sizes
        activation='relu',
        use_bias=True
    )
    
# Input layer using the graph tensor spec
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(type_spec=graph_tensor_spec)

# Apply the GCN model to the inputs
graph_setup = gcn_model(inputs,  edge_set_name="edges")
    
# Extract node states
node_states = graph_setup

decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid')
])

decoded = decoder(node_states)
#decoded = decoder(embeddings)

autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=decoded)

I setup the training as follows:
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()])
autoencoder.fit(
    x=graph,
    y=graph,  # For autoencoders, input = output
    epochs=1   # Number of training epochs
)

But when I do that, I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-c081c4864baa> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 autoencoder.fit(
      2     x=graph,
      3     y=graph,  # For autoencoders, input = output
      4     epochs=1   # Number of training epochs
      5 )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_gnn/graph/graph_piece.py in _unbatch(self)
    780     """Extension Types API: Unbatching."""
    781     if self.rank == 0:
--> 782       raise ValueError('Could not unbatch scalar (rank=0) GraphPiece.')
    783 
    784     def unbatch_fn(spec):

ValueError: Could not unbatch scalar (rank=0) GraphPiece.

I am assuming that the model expects batched format even though I only have 1 graph ? But im not sure how to fix this.
I dont see any documentation with regards to this.
I tried to train the graph but got an unbatched error which im not sure how to fix. I also suspect that it could be the way I'm feeding the data to "autoencoder.fit()" , maybe I'm not providing it in the right format but I'm not sure since the graph data is a Graph.Tensor

Yes, TF-GNN (like the vast majority of TF/Keras code) is written with the idea of training on a stream of batches of input data. Its user documentation explains the details, esp. the chapters on data preparation and the input pipeline.
By the way: To build a Graph Neural Network with TF-GNN's pre-defined models, you'd typically stack several GraphUpdate layers; the Conv layers are just a part of that. The chapter on modeling has more details.
Graph reconstruction is a complex task, and it might help to start from a working example and adapt it. (Unfortunately, I don't have a reference available for an example using TF-GNN.)
